# Difference between Hibernate Automatic value generation strategies?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

What is the difference between these two Automatic value generation strategies?

```
 1. @GeneratedValue
 2. @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is like following:

> **AUTO** Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.
>
> **IDENTITY**
>             Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using database identity column.
>
> **SEQUENCE**
>             Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using database sequence column.
>
> **TABLE**
>             Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.

Refer to the API here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html

Answer (score 4):

If you don't set the strategy attribute, it defaults to `AUTO`.
From the Hibernate docs:
AUTO: selects IDENTITY, SEQUENCE or TABLE depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database.

Comment: there must be difference between those two i.e. auto and identity.

Comment: There **can** be a difference but it's not a **must** requirement. JPA Provider can make `IDENTITY` generator a default one. In this case `AUTO` and `IDENTITY` will be the same.

Comment: The question was about hibernate, not JPA, at least it's tagged with hibernate.

Comment: @david Hibernate is a JPA provider (I'm referring to the latest versions). Moreover, `GeneratedValue` is a JPA annotation. I can't find Hibernate specific @GeneratedValue annotation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/javadoc/).

Comment: @Piotr: I used [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) as a reference. Under section 5.1.2.2. Otherwise you are right, but historically they are not the same.

Comment: @David - Sure. Just to sum up "Hibernate offers various generation strategies, let's explore the most common ones first **that happens to be standardized by JPA**." from the source you pointed.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that @GeneratedValue uses AUTO strategy as default while @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY) uses IDENTITY strategy

Here are the different options for strategy

AUTO - Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.

IDENTITY - Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using database identity column.

SEQUENCE - Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using database sequence column.

TABLE - Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.