# Error creating bean in spring boot app for a repository [UnsatisfiedDependencyException]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

The full error is

```
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUserDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.XX.ZZ.repo.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
```

As I have searched, apparently the error is in the entity, but I don't know how to fix it.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62908817/18895342) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004953/18895342)

```
package com.XX.ZZ.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String hash;
}
```

```
package com.XX.ZZ.repo;

import com.XX.ZZ.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
}
```

application.properties

```
# MySQL configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/censored
spring.datasource.username=censored
spring.datasource.password=censored
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
# since Hibernate 6 there's no need to specify the MySQL dialect => https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-dialect/

# server port
server.port = 4400

# security - secret generated with 512bit security level with: https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/Security-Encryption-Key-Generator.aspx
custom.data.jwt.secret = censored
custom.data.jwt.expiration = 86400
```

Tell me if I need to provide more classes like the ones that appear in the error.

Comment: which version of spring boot do you use?

Comment: @AmirRad Maven 4.0.0, spring boot 3.0.1, java 17

Comment: First it's better change I'd generalization strategy to GenerationType.IDENTITY.

Comment: Second share your application.properties, pls

Comment: I was using GenerationType.IDENTITY, but changed it recently to try to solve this problem, as I thought it was related to the id parameter. Changed it back now, and updated the post with the application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Remove additional dependencies from maven pom, like jwt.
3 configurations you should have

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.marketplace.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project"})
@EntityScan("com.project.marketplace.domain")
```

Comment: I need this dependency for JWT: `<dependency><groupId>com.auth0</groupId><artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId><version>4.2.1</version></dependency>` Where are these 3 configurations or where should I put them?

Comment: for each dependency you should define also @Bean configuration, because by default Spring  for example searching database if DB dependencies in the POM

Comment: I will suggest generate online project with jhipster and have a look configurations https://start.jhipster.tech/